# Brute Force Matching with FAST in opencv

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, brute-force

I want to match an image with a frame in video and get coordinates from the matched object. I first used ORB descriptor with Brute - Force matcher but it also showed too many false results and did not detected much corners in my object in frame. Even the detected corners changed when I changed the position of the object. I used multiple objects even made many objects from clay with many pointed corners, but it failed.

Then I saw FAST descriptor which was able to get many corners and thus I think that it would detect good amount of corners from the object even when its far away. So I want to apply Brute - Force Matching to two objects by using FAST descriptors in Opencv - 2.4.9 python. Please anybody suggest me a way to do this.

OR is there any any other better way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you're asking a question, you should mention what have you tried so far and what problem or error you are having. Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: can you provide example images?